# Finding linear independenct vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so first I want to verify that $m$ vectors of length $n>m$ are linearly independent. I think I can do this by setting up a matrix and get the rank of this matrix by gauss-elimination.

However afterwards I want to get another vector that is linearly independent to the set I already have. Is there any easy fast way to get this? Maybe with the work I already did (gauss-elimination)?

I think I can just take a standard-basis vector where I have all zeroes after the gauss-elimination. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Sounds good, but depends on what "where I have all zeroes after the gauss-elimination" means exactly.

Comment: I wasn't actually applying gauss-elimination, I just eliminated as many entries of the rows below the first one as possible, such that I got at least one row that is completely eliminated, and that row would be the component i could take as standard basis vector.

Comment: Ok, that sounds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can proceed arranging the $m$ given vectors by rows and in the RREF matrix selecting any column index $i$ without pivot, then we can add the linearly independent vector $e_i$ to the set.

Comment: Edit: I understand now, thx.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege Yes of course!